# KivyMD MDList - Click on right Icon and pass list index to a function

Tags: python, list, kivy, kivymd

I have a IconRightWidget added into a TwoLineAvatarIconListItem. I can call a function when clicking on the icon. But the problem is, within the function, I need to identify the index of the list item I clicked to remove that list item. But I'm getting an error

Below is my python code:

```
    def disp_alarm_all(self):
        iconleft=IconLeftWidgetWithoutTouch(icon="bell")
        iconright= IconRightWidget(icon="minus")       
        listitem=TwoLineAvatarIconListItem(text="Alarm Time here",secondary_text="Sleep Alarm")
        listitem.add_widget(iconleft)
        listitem.add_widget(iconright)
        iconright.bind(on_release=self.delete_active_alarm)
        self.root.ids.alarm_list_a.add_widget(listitem)

    def delete_active_alarm(self,listdata):
        sizelist=len(self.root.ids.alarm_list_a.children)
        sindex = sizelist-1-self.root.ids.alarm_list_a.children.index(listdata)
        if self.listitem_list_a[sindex].secondary_text == "Sleep Alarm":
            #do delete list item here
```

when I run this, I'm getting the error below pointing at the line "self.root.ids.alarm_list_a.children.index(listdata)" above:

Exception has occurred: ValueError
<kivymd.uix.list.list.IconRightWidget object at 0x0000023AF12B8C90> is not in list